# How i can do " A Datepicker with 3 separate input one for month , day and year and validate it"?

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to do is validate the three different inputs. If in month I put 02 which is February, in day I can not put 29 because that month does not have 29, same with the other months that only have 30.

Only and could validate the month that the input of the month can not exceed 12

```html
    <input type="number" id="month" class="form-control" min="1" max="12" oninput="(!validity.rangeOverflow||(value=12)) && (!validity.rangeUnderflow||(value=0)) &&(!validity.stepMismatch||(value=parseInt(this.value)));" placeholder="Month" required>
```

I hope when in the month put February do not let me put more than the number 28, if I put April do not let me put more than 30 ect

Answer (score 1):

Call this function on change event of input control

```
<input id="day" type = "text" onchange= "isValidDate();" onkeypress= "this.onchange();" onpaste= "this.onchange();" oninput = "this.onchange();"/>

<input id="month" type = "text" onchange= "isValidDate();" onkeypress= "this.onchange();" onpaste= "this.onchange();" oninput = "this.onchange();"/>

<input id="year" type = "text" onchange= "isValidDate();" onkeypress= "this.onchange();" onpaste= "this.onchange();" oninput = "this.onchange();"/>

 function isValidDate() {

      var day = Number(document.getElementById("day").value);
      var month = Number(document.getElementById("month").value);
      var year = Number(document.getElementById("year").value);

      var date = new Date();
      date.setFullYear(year, month - 1, day);
      // month - 1 since the month index is 0-based (0 = January)

      if ( (date.getFullYear() == year) && (date.getMonth() == month + 1) && (date.getDate() == day) )
        return true;

      return false;
    }
```

[source](https://ctrlq.org/code/20109-javascript-date-valid)